# How to know a device is FCC certified?

Tags: fcc

How can I know an electronic device has been passed FCC test?

Answer (score 2):

In the general case you can't.  Unintentional radiators aren't required to be certified.  If tests were done, the results will usually be private between the test house and the company that commissioned the tests.

In the special case of intentional radiators, they do need to be certified, and I believe the certification number must be displayed on the device somehow.  For large boxes, this is usually on the plaque near the power cord that lists the input power required, the fuse size, applicable patents, etc.  For small devices, this may be a small sticker on the back someplace, moulded into the plastic housing, or something.

Answer (score 1):

The FCC OET has an [Equipment Authorization Search](https://apps.fcc.gov/oetcf/eas/reports/GenericSearch.cfm) webpage. If you have the FCC ID of the device you can look it up on that webpage for details. And yes the device should have the FCC logo as others have suggested.

I don't think all RF equipment need to have a FCC ID

Comment: All intentionally RF radiating equipment does need a FCC ID to be legally sold in the US.